# Unable to update images on articles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary

I am using carrierwave and cloudinary gems to attach images on my article model. The create function works ok but when i need to update the existin images i am getting the bellow error :

'undefined method `reject' for "image/upload/v1557497204/hqef7unyuvfsva933idv.jpg":String'.

However if i go back and refresh the article page the new image is there

```
def update
        @article = Article.find(params[:id]) 
        if @article.update(article_params)#the error raised here
            flash[:notice] = "Your Article was Created"
            redirect_to @article
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end
```

Comment: The error is more likely raised in your model or your uploader. Please post the model at a minimum

Comment: Is this a multiple image upload? How many images are you uploading? How many images are you seeing?

Comment: @VeridianDynamics yes is multiple image upload . 
Model
````has_many :comments , dependent: :destroy
 mount_uploaders :image, ImageUploader
 serialize :image, JSON
````
Up loader
````
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
 
end

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you're SOL. I just posted my response based on Cloudinary's gem repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may very well be caused by a known issue: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/issues/266

It looks unsolved at the moment for multiple image uploads.

Comment: Yes, that forum lists one below the first comment: https://github.com/taragano/Cloudinary_multiple_uploads. However I don't recommend you work too hard to keep Cloudinary. They are *far* more expensive than the alternative: AWS S3 buckets. Though AWS can feel a little confusing, I think they are a cheaper, easier, alternative to Cloudinary (I migrated my Rails app 4 years ago and never looked back!)